SendGrid API Key evaluating to "undefined"?
I'm following the integration guide for Node.js with sendgrid. My environment variable folder looks like :
[removed api key]
And my 'index.js' looks like :
console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'evan.dickinson.flinn@gmail.com',
  from: 'improvedpts@improvedpts.com', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {}, error => {
    console.error(error);

    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body)
    }
  });


This is all copy & pasted from the tutorial sent by sendgrid

I also have a package.json file, but besides that those are the only three files in my folder. The error message I keep getting is:
API key does not start with "SG.".

And when I checked with console.log, my API key was apparently undefined? Can someone explain this to me? I've been scouring the internet but I haven't figured it out.
I want the API to send a email. I've tried importing 'dotenv', but that did not work so I went back to what the tutorial said. None of the online solutions have worked.

In addition to csevero's answer: Please delete this API and create a new one to protect your account

You can set up your Nodejs project with "dotenv" library to create and access environment variables.

Install the lib using npm i dotenv
Create a file in the root project with the name .env
Put your variables on the file

SENDGRID_API_KEY='SG.XXXXX'


Now you can get this variable easily in your code


const { config } = require('dotenv');
config();

console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'evan.dickinson.flinn@gmail.com',
  from: 'improvedpts@improvedpts.com', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {}, error => {
    console.error(error);

    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body)
    }
  });


I hope that it can help you :D.
Don't put API keys in questions.

helpful - thanks for the information!
